# Adding padding for the top axis of plt.matshow() not working

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to add padding for the top axis of plt.matshow()

I have tried to use various different method but still, I end up with essentially this result:

[image: matplotlib output]

Code tried:

```
pca_10 = PCA(10)  # project from 61 to 10 dimensions
projected_10 = pca_10.fit_transform(df)
print(df.shape)
print(projected_10.shape)

plt.figure(figsize=(20,14))
plt.matshow(pca_10.components_,cmap='viridis')
y_ticks_names = ['1st Comp','2nd Comp','3rd Comp', '4th Comp', '5th Comp', '6th Comp', '7th Comp', 
'8th Comp', '9th Comp', '10th Comp']
plt.yticks([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],y_ticks_names,fontsize=10)
plt.colorbar()
plt.xticks(range(len(df.columns)),df.columns,rotation=65,ha='left')
#plt.tight_layout(h_pad=200)
#plt.margins(50,50)
#plt.set_ylim(len(df.columns)-0.5, -0.5)
#plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.3,top=0.6)
#plt.ylim(10, 0)
#plt.gcf().subplots_adjust(hspace=0.3,top=0.6)
plt.gcf().tight_layout(rect=[0, 0.03, 1, 0.95])
plt.savefig(r'PCA_10_comps.png')
plt.show()
```

I tried each commented line to no avail.

Has anyone been able to make the saved image with correct padding at the top?

I have used plt.tight_layout() to good effect on other charts but Matplotlib doesn't like one or both of my axes this time around. Not sure why?:

[image: plt.tight_layout() not working]

Comment: Some of the commented lines are mutually exclusive. In theory, `plt.tight_layout()` alone should be sufficient. If it isn't, please provide a [mcve] (i.e. minimal runnable code).

Comment: Yeah, I thought tight layout would be enough, that's what I normally use. I added an extra screen-shot to show the error I receive. I tried each of the commented lines one after another not together and none of them seemed to work. I will add some small dummy data array into the code snipped to enable that others can reproduce! Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears I can answer my own question after some fairly long amount of time digging in the docs etc. and playing around.

Seems that if I move from `plt.figure()` to `fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()` then I can use `fig.tight_layout()` to good success.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
plt.style.use('ggplot')
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from sklearn import decomposition
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs

from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
```

Required imports, followed by new code:

```
pca_10 = PCA(10)  # project from 61 to 10 dimensions
projected_10 = pca_10.fit_transform(df)
print(df.shape)
print(projected_10.shape)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,4.5))
ax1.matshow(pca_10.components_,cmap='viridis')
y_ticks_names = ['1st Comp','2nd Comp','3rd Comp', '4th Comp', '5th Comp', '6th Comp', '7th Comp', '8th Comp', '9th Comp', '10th Comp']
ax1.set_yticks([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
ax1.set_yticklabels(y_ticks_names,fontsize=10)
ax1.set_xticks(range(len(df.columns)))
ax1.set_xticklabels(df.columns,rotation=65,ha='left')
fig.colorbar(cm.ScalarMappable(norm=None, cmap='viridis'), ax=ax1)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.savefig(r'PCA_10_comps.png')
plt.show()
```

Results in the desired output (also as the saved image in the current working directory):

[image: New fig, ax1 style]

Seems to suggest that for the matshow chart type, the `fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()` approach might be better?